# Lenovo X220 right click does not work with ubuntu 12.04

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

I am unable to right click with my new X220 Lenovo sub-notebook. I have read several workaround but even not know which one would help me. Can someone help me to find the solution or workaround?

```
dpkg-buildpackage: export CFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security
dpkg-buildpackage: export CPPFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
dpkg-buildpackage: export CXXFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security
dpkg-buildpackage: export FFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -g -O2
dpkg-buildpackage: export LDFLAGS from dpkg-buildflags (origin: vendor): -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro
dpkg-buildpackage: source package xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 1.6.2-1ubuntu1~precise2
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Timo Aaltonen <tjaalton@ubuntu.com>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 dpkg-source --before-build xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-1.6.2
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean --with quilt,autoreconf,xsf --builddirectory=build/
   dh_testdir -O--builddirectory=build/
   dh_auto_clean -O--builddirectory=build/
   dh_quilt_unpatch -O--builddirectory=build/
Removing patch 131_reset-num_active_touches-on-deviceoff.patch
Restoring src/synaptics.c

Removing patch 130_dont_enable_rightbutton_area.patch
Restoring conf/50-synaptics.conf

Removing patch 129_disable_three_touch_tap.patch
Restoring src/synaptics.c

Removing patch 128_disable_three_click_action.patch
Restoring src/synaptics.c

Removing patch 126_ubuntu_xi22.patch
Restoring configure.ac

Removing patch 125_option_rec_revert.patch
Restoring test/fake-symbols.h
Restoring test/fake-symbols.c

Removing patch 124_syndaemon_events.patch
Restoring tools/syndaemon.c

Removing patch 118_quell_error_msg.patch
Restoring tools/synclient.c
Restoring tools/syndaemon.c

Removing patch 115_evdev_only.patch
Restoring conf/50-synaptics.conf

Removing patch 106_always_enable_vert_edge_scroll.patch
Restoring src/synaptics.c

Removing patch 104_always_enable_tapping.patch
Restoring src/synaptics.c

Removing patch 103_enable_cornertapping.patch
Restoring src/synaptics.c

Removing patch 101_resolution_detect_option.patch
Restoring include/synaptics-properties.h
Restoring man/synaptics.man
Restoring src/synapticsstr.h
Restoring src/properties.c
Restoring src/synaptics.c
Restoring tools/synclient.c

Removing patch 02-do-not-use-synaptics-for-keyboards.patch
Restoring conf/11-x11-synaptics.fdi

No patches applied
   dh_autoreconf_clean -O--builddirectory=build/
   dh_clean -O--builddirectory=build/
 dpkg-source -b xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-1.6.2
dpkg-source: warning: no source format specified in debian/source/format, see dpkg-source(1)
dpkg-source: info: using source format `1.0'
dpkg-source: info: building xserver-xorg-input-synaptics using existing xserver-xorg-input-synaptics_1.6.2.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: building xserver-xorg-input-synaptics in xserver-xorg-input-synaptics_1.6.2-1ubuntu1~precise2.diff.gz
dpkg-source: warning: the diff modifies the following upstream files: 
 autogen.sh
 docs/README.alps
 docs/tapndrag.dia
 docs/trouble-shooting.txt
dpkg-source: info: use the '3.0 (quilt)' format to have separate and documented changes to upstream files, see dpkg-source(1)
dpkg-source: info: building xserver-xorg-input-synaptics in xserver-xorg-input-synaptics_1.6.2-1ubuntu1~precise2.dsc
 debian/rules build
dh build --with quilt,autoreconf,xsf --builddirectory=build/
   dh_testdir -O--builddirectory=build/
   dh_quilt_patch -O--builddirectory=build/
Applying patch 02-do-not-use-synaptics-for-keyboards.patch
patching file conf/11-x11-synaptics.fdi
Hunk #1 succeeded at 9 (offset 7 lines).

Applying patch 101_resolution_detect_option.patch
patching file include/synaptics-properties.h
patching file man/synaptics.man
patching file src/properties.c
Hunk #3 succeeded at 787 (offset 6 lines).
patching file src/synaptics.c
Hunk #2 succeeded at 1403 (offset 3 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 1421 (offset 3 lines).
patching file src/synapticsstr.h
patching file tools/synclient.c

Applying patch 103_enable_cornertapping.patch
patching file src/synaptics.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 762 with fuzz 1 (offset 202 lines).

Applying patch 104_always_enable_tapping.patch
patching file src/synaptics.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 662 with fuzz 2 (offset 6 lines).

Applying patch 106_always_enable_vert_edge_scroll.patch
patching file src/synaptics.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 673 (offset 174 lines).

Applying patch 115_evdev_only.patch
patching file conf/50-synaptics.conf
Hunk #1 succeeded at 14 with fuzz 2.

Applying patch 118_quell_error_msg.patch
patching file tools/synclient.c
patching file tools/syndaemon.c

Applying patch 124_syndaemon_events.patch
patching file tools/syndaemon.c

Applying patch 125_option_rec_revert.patch
patching file test/fake-symbols.c
patching file test/fake-symbols.h

Applying patch 126_ubuntu_xi22.patch
patching file configure.ac

Applying patch 128_disable_three_click_action.patch
patching file src/synaptics.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 671 (offset 174 lines).

Applying patch 129_disable_three_touch_tap.patch
patching file src/synaptics.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 665 (offset 32 lines).

Applying patch 130_dont_enable_rightbutton_area.patch
patching file conf/50-synaptics.conf

Applying patch 131_reset-num_active_touches-on-deviceoff.patch
patching file src/synaptics.c

Applying patch 201-wait.patch
patching file src/eventcomm.c
Hunk #1 FAILED at 750.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 775.
Hunk #3 FAILED at 784.
3 out of 3 hunks FAILED -- rejects in file src/eventcomm.c
Patch 201-wait.patch does not apply (enforce with -f)
dh_quilt_patch: quilt --quiltrc /dev/null push -a || test $? = 2 returned exit code 1
make: *** [build] Error 25
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/X220#Touchpad

> Right click can be fixed by patching the xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
>   package with the following these steps (source):

```
mkdir tmpbuild
cd tmpbuild/
wget http://david.hardeman.nu/synaptics-suse-patches.tar.bz2
apt-get source xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
cd xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-1.3.99+git20110116.0e27ce3a/
cd debian/patches/
tar xfj ../../../synaptics-suse-patches.tar.bz2 
ls -1 2*.patch >> series
cd ../../
sudo apt-get build-dep xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -rfakeroot
sudo dpkg -i ../xserver-xorg-input-synaptics_1.3.99+git20110116.0e27ce3a-0ubuntu12_amd64.deb
```

Comment: If you depended on Right-Click to paste into the shell, then `CTRL+SHIFT+V` works as well

Comment: I have tried the aboves and got error message at the end.

Comment: can you post your error messages?